# Single-line if statements in C - which statements are affected?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to translate some code from C to another language. I don't have a quick access to a C compiler and just found myself confused with the single-line if statements. I know that statements like:

```
if (condition) [statement]
```

and

```
if (condition)
    [statement]
```

can be evaluated without the brackets, i.e. are equivalent to:

```
if (condition) {[statement]}
```

and

```
if (condition)
    {[statement]}
```

respectively, but I'm not sure about the sample code I'm dealing with. It goes:

```
if (ge.g[*l][*k].s==1) *i=1; else *i=Ne;  
*j=*l;
```

I feel like the second line is not affected by the if statement, but it's not immediately obvious from the context of the code. Long story short: is the above equivalent to:

```
if (ge.g[*l][*k].s==1) {*i=1;} else {*i=Ne;}  
*j=*l;
```

or

```
if (ge.g[*l][*k].s==1) {*i=1;} else {*i=Ne;  
*j=*l;}
```

?

Comment: In absence of brackets only the first statement is considered part of the if-else block. So it is equivalent to the first of your options.

Comment: Why would the `else` slurp up multiple statements? BTW the number of lines is irrelevant.

Comment: 'I don't have a quick access to a C compiler' download one and a debugger.  You will need one anyway for test/debug, and getting the tools now will allow you to test out any such confusions.

Comment: .. or just try it out on an online compiler.

Comment: If you use an `if` statement, 1) do not omit brackets, and 2) do not place two brackets on the same line. You won't destroy your SSD by storing these several extra characters. However, if a ternary operator might make the expression more readable, like this: `*i = (stuff==1) ? 1 : Ne`, then it's possible to save some typing.

Answer (score 5):

Following code

```
if (ge.g[*l][*k].s==1) *i=1; else *i=Ne;  
*j=*l;
```

when formatted correctly is written like this:

```
if (ge.g[*l][*k].s==1)
   *i=1;
 else
   *i=Ne;  

*j=*l;
```

and this is the equivalent code *with* braces:

```
if (ge.g[*l][*k].s==1)
{
   *i=1;
}
else
{
   *i=Ne;  
}

*j=*l;
```

This shows the importance of code being formatted correctly so it is readable and understandable also by humans and not only by comilers.

Comment: It also shows how brackets can save you a lot of guess work.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying brackets

> {}

create a "compound" statement (I know that the C scholars will be very upset seeing this "definition") . In your question the single statement can be replaced by the compound one (in the braces). The position of the statement does not matter as the most of whitespace is ignored by the compiler (except the strings & everything processed by the preprocessor). You can even add 100000 newlines and it will not change anything. It is only important for us humans :)

```
if(x==y)start(x);else start(y);
```

===

```
if (x == y)
    start(x);
else 
    start(y);
```

===

```
if      (x       ==                  y)





                                                                start(              x          ); 



                                                                 else 




start(                                           y)                        

;
```

but the second one is the easiest one to read IMHO :)

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces actually group a number of statements as one compound statement.

`if` has a syntax like the following:

```
if (condition) statement1 [else statement2]
```

*where [ ] indicates: optional*

Now `statement1` can be a single statement (delimited by a semicolon), or a so-called compound statement, i.e. a group of subsequent statements enclosed in curly braces. The same is true for `statement2`.

That is why your first alternative is correct. If the second line were involved too, braces would have to be used, to group the statements together into one compound statement. Since there are no "curlies", the first alternative is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Single Statement (without bracket).

**One statement** is an operation that **ends with single ; sign**.

```
if (condition)
    statement 1;
```

example:

```
 if (ge.g[*l][*k].s==1) 
     *i=1;  // statement 1
 else 
     *i=Ne; // statement 1

 *j=*l; // statement 2
```

> Single Statement (with bracket).

```
if (condition) {
    statement 1;
}
```

example:

```
 if (ge.g[*l][*k].s==1)  {
     *i=1;  // statement 1
 }
 else {
     *i=Ne; // statement 1
 }

 *j=*l; // statement 2
```

> Multiple Statement (with brackets)

**Brackets {** are **only needed** when your statement is **more than one**.

```
if (condition) {
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
    statement n;
}
```

example:

```
 if (ge.g[*l][*k].s==1) {
     *i++; // statement 1
     *i++; // statement 2
     *i++; // statement 3
 }
```